# Find the email address that occurs the most in a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have to go through a txt file which contains all manner of info and pull the email address that occurs the most therewithin.

My code is as follows, but it does not work. It prints no output and I am not sure why. Here is the code:

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
names = handle.readlines()
count = dict()
for name in names:
    name = name.split()
    for letters in name:
        if '@' not in letters: 
            name.remove(letters)
        else: 
            continue
    name = str(name)
    if name not in count:
        count[name] = 1
    else: 
        count[name] = count[name]+ 1
print(max(count, key=count.get(1)))
```

As I understand it, this code works as follows:

we first open the file, then we read the lines, then we create an empty dict

Then in the first for loop, we split the txt file into a list based on each line.
Then, in the second for loop, for each item in each line, if there is no @, then it is removed.
We then return for the original for loop, where, if the name is not a key in dict, it is added with a value of 1; else one is added to its value.

Finally, we print the max key & value.

Where did I go wrong???

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: If there is no output, what error(s) were reported?

Comment: Have you checked that `names` contains the expected text and that `counts` contains the expected entries? This narrows down the source of your problem. For future problems, [this blog entry](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) will help you to address the common "Where is the bug?" question.

Comment: Thanks for the link Mr. T! Lol after reading this I gotta apologize for my poor etiquette here

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the last line to:

```
print(max(count, key=count.get))
```

**EDIT**

For sake of more explanation:

You were providing `max()` with the wrong ordering function by `key=count.get(1)`.

So, `count.get(1)` would return default value or None when the key argument you passed to `get()` isn't in the dictionary.

If so, `max()` would then behave by outputing the max string key in your dictionary (as long as all your keys are strings and your dictionary is not empty).

Comment: As others have pointed out, there are better practices to do what you are trying to do (i.e using regex .. etc).

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following code:

```
names = '''hola@hola.com
whatsap@hola.com
hola@hola.com
hola@hola.com
klk@klk.com
klk@klk.com
klk@klk.com
klk@klk.com
klk@klk.com
whatsap@hola.com'''
count = list(names.split("\n"))
sett = set(names.split("\n"))

highest = count.count(count[0])
theone = count[0]
for i in sett:
    l = count.count(i)
    if l > highest:
        highest = l
        theone = i
print(theone)
```

Output:

```
klk@klk.com
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The OP did not ask what other approaches exist (they are numerous) but why their code does not give the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Import Regular Expressions (`re`) as it will help in getting emails.

```
import re
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
names = "\n".join(handle.readlines())
email_ids = re.findall(r"[0-9a-zA-Z._+%]+@[0-9a-zA-Z._+%]+[.][0-9a-zA-Z.]+", names)
email_ids = [(email_ids.count(email_id), email_id) for email_id in email_ids].sort(reverse=True)
email_ids = set([i[1] for i in email_ids)
```

In the variable `email_ids` you will get a set of the emails arranged on the basis of their occurrences, in descending order.

I know that the `code` is lengthy and has a few redundant lines, but there are there to make the `code` self-explanatory.